# Created datapoints that should form a sphere form a circle instead..?

Tags: c++, 3d, geometry

I am at the moment trying to form transformation matrices which translational part should form a sphere around an object, given its the center.

Problem is though, that's not happening, as I'm only getting a circle out of it, which I don't understand.

[image: datapoints visualized]

The red dots are those points I've computed and the blue dot should be the center of the sphere..

```
std::vector<Transform3D<>> sphere(double dx, double dy, double dz, Transform3D<> T_toolFrame_TCP)
{
    double r = 0.01; // Radius of the sphere -  set to 0.50 cm (TODO: has to be checked if that also is accurate)

    cout << endl;
    cout << "Create a sphere" << endl;

    double current_x = T_toolFrame_TCP.P()[0];
    double current_y = T_toolFrame_TCP.P()[1];
    double current_z = T_toolFrame_TCP.P()[2];


    // Formula for sphere (x-x0)²+(y-y0)²+(z-z0)²=r²
    // x: x = x_0 + rcos(theta)sin(phi)
    // y: y = y_0 + rsin(theta)sin(phi)
    // z: z = z_0 + rcos(phi)
    // Angle range: 0 <= theta <= 2M_PI ; 0 <= phi <= M_PI

    double obj_x = current_x + dx;
    double obj_y = current_y + dy;
    double obj_z = current_z + dz;
    cout << obj_x <<" , "<< obj_y <<" , "<< obj_z << endl;
    std::vector<Transform3D<>> out;

    int i = 0;
    for(double azimuthal = 0; azimuthal <= 2*M_PI ; azimuthal+=0.1 ) // In a circle
    {

        for(double polar = 0.34; polar <= M_PI-0.35 ; polar+=0.1 ) // Top to bottom
        {

            double sphere_x = obj_x + r*cos(azimuthal)*sin(polar);
            double sphere_y = obj_y + r*sin(azimuthal)*sin(polar);
            double sphere_z = obj_z + + r*cos(polar);

            Transform3D<> transformation_matrix = transform(obj_x,obj_y,obj_z,sphere_x,sphere_y,sphere_z);
            out.push_back(transformation_matrix);

        }
    }
    cout << i << " " << out.size() << endl;
    return out;
}

Transform3D<> pathPlanning::transform(double obj_x, double obj_y, double obj_z, double sphere_x, double sphere_y ,double sphere_z)
{
    // Z-axis should be oriented towards the object.
    // Rot consist of 3 direction vector [x,y,z] which describes how the axis should be oriented in the world space.
    // Looking at the simulation the z-axis is the camera out. X, and Y describes the orientation of the camera.
    // The vector are only for direction purposes, so they have to be normalized....

    //cout << endl;
    //cout << "inside Transform" << endl;
    //cout << obj_x <<" "<<  sphere_x << " ; "  << obj_y <<" "<<  sphere_y  <<" ; "<< obj_z <<" "<< sphere_z  << endl;
    Vector3D<> dir_z(double(obj_x - sphere_x), double(obj_y - sphere_y), double(obj_z - sphere_z));
    //Vector3D<> dir_z((sphere_x-obj_x), (sphere_y - obj_y), (sphere_z-obj_z));
    dir_z = normalize(dir_z);
    Vector3D<> downPlane(0.0,0.0,-1.0);
    Vector3D<> dir_x = cross(downPlane,dir_z);
    dir_x = normalize(dir_x);
    Vector3D<> dir_y = cross(dir_z,dir_x);
    dir_y = normalize(dir_y);

    Rotation3D<> rot_out (dir_x,dir_y,dir_z);  // [x y z]

    Vector3D<> pos_out(sphere_x,sphere_y,sphere_z);

    Transform3D<> out(pos_out,rot_out);
    //cout << endl;
    //cout << "desired: " << endl << out.R().e() << endl << endl  << out.P().e() << endl;

    return out;
}
```

Each `Transform3D<>` is just a 4x4 matrix which contains `[x_vec y_vec z_vec position]`
`Vector3D<>` is just a vector which contains 3 elements. 
Each `Rotation3D<>` is just a 3x3 matrix which contains [x_vec,y_vec,z_vec].

Each `Transform3D<>` can be constructed from a `Rotation3D<>` and `Vector3D<>`

The objective of the `sphere` function is to find all the positions on the sphere created around the object. The function is given a `dx,dy,dz, t_toolFrame_TCP` which tells the function how far the center of the sphere should be according to its current position which is given by t_toolFrame_TCP.P().

The t_toolFrame_TCP I use is

```
 6.12323e-17  6.12323e-17           -1  -3.55148e-18
          -1   3.7494e-33 -6.12323e-17             0
           0            1  6.12323e-17         0.091
           0            0            0             1
```

For some reason are the points not forming a sphere which I have no clue why it is happening? could someone elaborate me on my problem?

Comment: try remove the double `+ +` from `double sphere_z = obj_z + + r*cos(polar);` so it will became `double sphere_z = obj_z + r*cos(polar);` It should not matter but weird compiler bugs are always possible (have seen a lot of them across many compilers). Also your `polar` range is suspicious I would use `<-0.5*M_PI,+0.5*M_PI>` Which axis is not generated properly?

Comment: What is `Rotation3D` may be it is not doing what you are expecting try to construct the matrix yourself (you already got the axis vectors so it is easy) see [Understanding 4x4 homogenous transform matrices](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28084380/2521214). And lastly try to plot your raw points (without transformation) to check if the sphere coordinates are generated properly (so you isolate where the error is).